# How to write a Redux ReactJS modal component correctly?

Tags: reactjs, redux, components

On one page I use 2 or more modals with different content. Now for each modal window, I create a reducer that stores isOpen: true / false. Is this a normal solution? It confuses me that I have to create a reducer for a new modal window in applications.
I would like to of course use only 1 reducer so that I can reuse the modal window component. And I ran into a problem when, when the modal window was opened, the rest were opened along with it.

Comment: Perhaps you could provide a runnable example demonstrating the problem and indicate specifically what in that example isn't working as expected?

Answer (score 0):

Is hard to help with no example code. But based on what you described it looks that you'll need two states. isOpenModal1 and isOpenModal2. You can combine them in a single reducer like this:

```
import { createStore } from 'redux';
const rootReducer = (state,action)=>{
    switch(action.type){
        case 'OPEN_MODAL_1':
            return {...state, isOpenModal1:true}
        case 'CLOSE_MODAL_1':
            return {...state, isOpenModal1:false}
        case 'OPEN_MODAL_2':
            return {...state, isOpenModal2:true}
        case 'OPEN_MODAL_2':
            return {...state, isOpenModal2:false}
        default:
            return state
     }
}

const initState = {
    isOpenModal1: false,
    isOpenModal2: false
}
const store = createStore(rootReducer,initState);
export default store;
```

And when you need to close/open the modal you can use use useDispatch:

```
const Open1 = () => { dispatch({ type: "OPEN_MODAL_1" }) };
```